# How can I replace braces with <?php ?> in php file?

Tags: php, str-replace

I wanna replace braces with  `<?php ?>` in a file with php extension.
I have a class as a library and in this class I have three function like these:

```
 function replace_left_delimeter($buffer)
{
    return($this->replace_right_delimeter(str_replace("{", "<?php echo $", $buffer)));
}

function replace_right_delimeter($buffer)
{
    return(str_replace("}", "; ?> ", $buffer));
}

function parser($view,$data)
{
    ob_start(array($this,"replace_left_delimeter"));
    include APP_DIR.DS.'view'.DS.$view.'.php';
    ob_end_flush();
}
```

and I have a view file with php extension like this:

```
{tmp} tmpstr
```

in output I save just tmpstr and in source code in browser I get

```
<?php echo $tmp; ?> 
tmpstr
```

In include file `<?` shown as `<!--?` and be comment. Why?

Comment: editing a php page with php is generally a bad idea

Comment: @Dagon I don't want You to say your point about idea! If you can't help me why give me unlike?!!!! :|

Comment: If you don't want my opinion. Don't post. The first down vote was not mine, but the second one will be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this:

```
function parser($view,$data)
{
    $data=array("data"=>$data);
    $template=file_get_contents(APP_DIR.DS.'view'.DS.$view.'.php');
    $replace = array();
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        #if $data is array...
        $replace = array_merge(
            $replace,array("{".$key."}"=>$value)
            );
    }

    $template=strtr($template,$replace);
    echo $template;
}
```

and ignore other two functions.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do here won't work. The replacements carried out by the output buffering callback occur after PHP code has already been parsed and executed. Introducing new PHP code tags at this stage won't cause them to be executed.

You will need to instead preprocess the PHP source file before evaluating it, e.g.

```
$tp = file_get_contents(APP_DIR.DS.'view'.DS.$view.'.php');
$tp = str_replace("{", "<?php echo \$", $tp);
$tp = str_replace("}", "; ?>", $tp);
eval($tp);
```

However, I'd strongly recommend using an existing template engine; this approach will be inefficient and limited. You might want to give [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) a shot, for instance.

Comment: Thanks a lot. :) In include file "<?" shown as <!--? and be comment. Why?

Comment: and also in your code I get a error like this: ` Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in D:\xampp\htdocs\form2\system\View.php(31) : eval()'d code on line 1`

Comment: There may be a syntax issue in your template. Consider printing `$tp` instead of evaluating it for testing purposes, and make sure the results make sense.

Comment: my template is just this: `{tmp} tmpstr`

Answer (score 0):

How does this work:

**process.php**:

```
<?php

$contents = file_get_contents('php://stdin');

$contents = preg_replace('/\{([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*)\}/', '<?php echo $\1; ?>', $contents);
echo $contents;
```

**bash script**:

```
process.php < my_file.php
```

Note that the above works by doing a one-off search and replace. You can easily modify the script if you want to do this on the fly.

Note also, that modifying PHP code from within PHP code is a bad idea. Self-modifying code can lead to hard-to-find bugs, and is often associated with malicious software. If you explain what you are trying to achieve - your purpose - you might get a better response.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand which code is for which part? :(

Comment: I wanna replace theme in include file.

Comment: `process.php` is a PHP script that will perform the replacement. `my_file.php` is the file in which you want the replacements made. `bash script` is what you execute from the command line.

Comment: Thank you. But in include file  "<?" shown as <!--? and be comment